# How to solve $(1+i\sqrt{3})^{-1+i}$??

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Good morning, I want to solve this... but I lose my way. I hope somebody help me... I show you my calculus

---

$(1+i\sqrt{3})^{-1+i}=e^{(-1+i)\log(-1+i)}$

$(1+i\sqrt{3})^{-1+i}=e^{(-1+i)(\log 2+i\frac{\pi}{3})}$

$(1+i\sqrt{3})^{-1+i}=e^{-\log 2-\frac{\pi}{3}+i\log2-i\frac{\pi}{3}}$

$(1+i\sqrt{3})^{-1+i}=e^{(-\log 2-\frac{\pi}{3})+i(\log2-\frac{\pi}{3})}$

$(1+i\sqrt{3})^{-1+i}=e^{(-\log 2-\frac{\pi}{3})}[\cos(\log2-\frac{\pi}{3})+i \sin(\log2-\frac{\pi}{3})]$

I not sure...

Comment: This is going to have infinitely many values. You want the end of the second line to read $(-1+i)(\log 2 + i(2n\pi + \frac {\pi}3))$. In addition, your first line has a typo (it should say $\log (1+i\sqrt{3})$ in the far right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$ $z=(1+i\sqrt{3})^{-1+i} \iff z=e^{\ (-1+i) \log(1+i\sqrt{3})}$

$(2)$ Use $Log(z):= \ln |z| + i \arg(z)$

$(3)$ Here $|z|=2$ and $\arg(z)=\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n$ for any integer $n$

$(4)$ So, $z= e^{ (1+i)(2+i(\frac{\pi}{3}+2\pi n))}$

We can simplify this further, but I think this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is incorrect and should be deleted or the argument of $\log$ corrected to $(1+i\sqrt 3)$. The second line is correct if you are using the principal value of the complex logarithm. The rest is fine.